# karma-jasmine - how to test return object

Tags: jasmine, karma-jasmine, browserify, commonjs, istanbul

I'm trying to add a test that will cover the return statement in the CommonJS file, `module1.js`, please see the attached image.

Here's what I'm currently trying:

```
describe("Module 1 ", () => {
    let mod, testMod = null;

    beforeEach(() => {
        mod = {
            module1: require('../src/app/js/module1/module1')
        };

        spyOn(mod, 'module1');
        testMod = mod.module1();
        console.log(testMod);
        console.log(mod.module1);
    });
    it('is executed', () => {
        expect(mod.module1).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```

Module1 file:

```
/**
 * Represents module1.
 * @module module1
 */

function module1() {
    let x = 13;

    return {
        getUserAgent: getUserAgent
    };

    /**
     * Return the userAgent of the browser.
     * @func getUserAgent
     */
    function getUserAgent() {
        return window.navigator.userAgent
    }
}

module.exports = module1;
```

Log output:

```
LOG: undefined
LOG: function () { ... }
```

UPDATE: When I log `mod.module.toString`, the console logs:

`function () { return fn.apply(this, arguments); }`

Why isn't my module there?

Am I trying the right approach here? Why doesn't `mod.module1();` work?

[image: Istanbul coverage Report]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you set spy on object method in Jasmine the original function is not called. 
So in your example `mod.module1()` doesn call actual module function but only spy wrapper function - the actual function is not called at all.
If you want original function to be called you should use [`and.callThrough`](https://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Spies:_%3Ccode%3Eand.callThrough%3C/code%3E):

```
spyOn(mod, 'module1').and.callThrough();
```